# How to enable virtualization on Lenovo Z500?

Tags: kernel, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I have downloaded the Kernel 3.13.6 from kernel.org and installed in the system. 
Updated the BIOS and then enabled the virtualization in the bios settings. Now I have used the command

```
sudo kvm-ok
```

to check if virtualization is enabled, but it gives following :(

```
INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
INFO: Your CPU supports KVM extensions
KVM acceleration can be used
```

What else can I do in order to enable virtualization ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really hard question.

A little hint : `sudo modprobe kvm_intel`

Comment: thanks a ton :D that really helped. Now `sudo kvm-ok` gives the output `INFO: /dev/kvm exists
KVM acceleration can be used
` I can move forward with my work.